# How to exclude a controller of being redirect to https in ASP.NET Core 1.1

Tags: redirect, url-rewriting, asp.net-core-1.1

Following this nice article https://long2know.com/2016/07/asp-net-core-enforcing-https/ i try to enforce HTTPS but with the exception of one single web-api controller that have to response to an embedded system not capable of  SSL. The problem exist in the following Configure section of startup.cs.

```
        var options = new RewriteOptions()
           .AddRewrite("^api/&", "/api/", skipRemainingRules: true) 
           .AddRedirectToHttps(302, sslPort);

        app.UseRewriter(options);
```

With the AddRewrite line (that doesn't replace anything) i try to trigger skipRemainingRules in order to avert the redirection. This is working at development in IIS express (trough localhost) but not at the production enviroment behind IIS. Apperently the SkipRemainingRules does not prevent the AddRedirectToHttps of enter into force.

Many thanks for any clue the may solve this.

Answer (score 3):

I'm aware that my response is quite late, but maybe it will help someone.

```
var options = new RewriteOptions()
            .AddRewrite(@"^api/(.*)", "api/$1", true)
            .AddRedirectToHttps(302, sslPort);
app.UseRewriter(options);
```

With this solution one can call /api/... on http, every other request will be redirected to https.

I've testes this solution with .Net Core 2.1.

Answer (score 2):

I eventually fix it with a custom redirect:

```
public class CustomRedirect : Microsoft.AspNetCore.Rewrite.IRule
{
     public void ApplyRule(RewriteContext context)
    {
        var request = context.HttpContext.Request;
        var host = request.Host;

        // Exclude localhost
        if ( string.Equals(host.Host, "localhost", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
        {
            context.Result = RuleResult.ContinueRules;
            return;
        }

        // Exclude api
        if (request.Path.Value.Contains("/api/"))
        {
            context.Result = RuleResult.ContinueRules;
            return;
        }

        // force other traffic to https
        if (string.Equals(request.Scheme, "http", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
        {
            string path = "https://" + host.Value + request.PathBase + request.Path + request.QueryString;
            context.HttpContext.Response.Redirect(path,true);
            context.Result = RuleResult.EndResponse;
        }     
    }
}
```

And register in the Configure section of startup.cs:

app.UseRewriter(new RewriteOptions().Add(new CustomRedirect()));

Answer (score 0):

I think there was an [issue](https://github.com/aspnet/KestrelHttpServer/issues/916) working with IIS even in Azure web apps regarding http/https redirect.

So one way to acheive this is to enforce it via `web.config` like this:

```
<system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <rule name="HTTP/S to HTTPS Redirect" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
            <match url="^((?!api).)*$" />
            <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAny">
              <add input="{SERVER_PORT_SECURE}" pattern="^0$" />
            </conditions>
            <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}/{R:0}" redirectType="Permanent" />
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>
  </system.webServer>
```

By this convention you are enforcing `https` for every `url` except those with `api` keyword inside.

Comment: Thank you Yaser. I already did that directly at the IIS server and its works (as long as it is not replaced during deployment!). So i tried to move it to the project, also to keep in track with IIS Express during development. But as stated in the file itself 'web.config' is superseded by 'appsettings.json' and i can not find  find a decent way out overthere that fits both production and development enviroment. Nor in 'startup.cs'